# Testing a Docker Image

Tags: testing, docker

I'm working on writing test for a project and i want to test and verify a docker image build. But i don't want to push the image.

I want the image to build on a CI (like taskcluster) and run test.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Rao the question is how can i test docker builds without pushing local builds to the CI. I want the CI to build the image and test it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [`taskcluster/docker-worker`](https://github.com/taskcluster/docker-worker), that is a **[Docker worker](https://docs.taskcluster.net/manual/tasks/workers/docker-worker)** which is detailed in the [reference documentation](https://docs.taskcluster.net/reference/workers/docker-worker).

That worker include [test suites](https://docs.taskcluster.net/reference/workers/docker-worker#running-tests): you can see an example in [`taskcluster/mozilla-taskcluster`](https://github.com/taskcluster/mozilla-taskcluster/blob/master/src/config/test.yml).

Comment: Awesome. I've looked through that example. The problem is i don't want to push locally built images to the CI. i want the image to be built and verified on the CI.

I make use of taskcluster's provisional worker:
`- provisionerId: "{{ taskcluster.docker.provisionerId }}"`
`    workerType: "{{ taskcluster.docker.workerType }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Run test on source code than final image.

Create one build docker exactly with same environment as deployment docker.
Mount source code in build docker and run test cases inside build docker.If test cases are succeeded then only you build deployment image and push it.

Comment: Isn't there a way docker images can be built by the CI?

Comment: write simple makefile which will mount source code in build docker image then run test case on that docker container, then create docker, push it to registry.This what CI is all about. Submit code -> run testcase -> build deployment docker -> push it to registry -> deploy it to environment

Comment: do you have any resource that can help make the process clearer. I have a slight idea of what a makefile is but how to use it to do something like this is what i dont understand.

Comment: As of now there is no resource.Write a Makefile which has rules like docker-test and docker-push.In docker-test rule, run test cases in docker container which has same environment like deployment.Once docker-test executed ,parse test results and if all test cases are passed then execute docker-push.In docker-push,build docker and push it to CI.That way it will always check test case result before actually pushing image to CI.

Comment: Oh! Now i get you. The thing is i don't want to push the image to CI. I want the CI to build the image itself and test then delete when it's done. I don't want to push any image from my PC. @GirdharSojitra

Comment: Ohh sorry for confusion...I prefer running testcases on source code inside the container and for that source code input is required.I am not suggesting to test docker image instead test code in docker container